# Creating a new table using a synonym in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, synonym

I have a synonym created for this table `ParaPITD.dbo.BM_00_PolicyMaster` that points to `ParaPITDYYYYMM.dbo.BM_00_PolicyMaster`

There is no table yet - so it acts as a place holder.

I have a stored procedure that creates a temp table `#BM_00_PolicyMaster` and now I want to insert or select into the place holder where the synonym points to and create the table in `ParaPITDYYYYMM.dbo.BM_00_PolicyMaster`

If I run this:

```
select * 
into ParaPITD.dbo.BM_00_PolicyMaster
from #BM_00_PolicyMaster
```

it creates the table in `ParaPITD.dbo.BM_00_PolicyMaster` and ignores the synonym

If I run this:

```
INSERT INTO ParaPITD.dbo.BM_00_PolicyMaster
   SELECT * 
   FROM #BM_00_PolicyMaster
```

it gives me an invalid object error acting like the table must exist before it will insert.

Appreciate any help - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx):

> You cannot reference a synonym in a DDL statement

And any statement that creates a table, including `SELECT INTO` counts as a DDL statement.  (See here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1085a84c-faac-4d26-8f35-c64d8b901034/insert-into-is-sentence-dml-or-ddl)